# Java - Time limited tasks in a threadpool finish earnier than expected

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a problem understanding the bug. I have a code which runs tasks in a thread pool. But the time of execution of a single task is limited. Here is the code:

```
public static abstract class CustomRunnable implements Runnable {

    private CountDownLatch latch;

    public void setLatch(CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    protected void threadFinished() {
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

And executions:

```
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(threads.size());
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
    ScheduledExecutorService canceller = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    try {
        for(CustomRunnable thread : threads) {
            thread.setLatch(latch);
            Future<?> future = executor.submit(thread);
            canceller.schedule(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    future.cancel(true);
                    thread.threadFinished();
                }
            }, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }
        latch.await();
        executor.shutdown();
        canceller.shutdown();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But `latch.await();` fires much more earlier than expected (this code is used in a few places). Are there any ideas how to fix that? Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you cancel the future in the runnable that belongs to the future?

Comment: Your example is presented is incomplete - I've just run it and it does indeed wait for a minute before calling `threadFinished()` and tripping the latch.  I would guess that `threadFinished()` is being called from somewhere other than your cancellation runnable - try setting a breakpoint there to see when (and why) the latch gets counted down.

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, you don’t need a CountDownLatch.  You can wait for all of an ExecutorService’s tasks to finish by calling its [awaitTermination](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) method.

Comment: @VGR, I tested, in this case it waits exactly one minute to let finish for each thread. Is there a way to use this Timer to setup maximum execution time, and don't restrict it from the bottom?

Comment: @Robert, okay, but how it should work? I found an example on stackoverflow and adapted it for my case

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle, yes, it also can be called when thread is finished by itself, but not timer